# Identifying duplicates in Haskell tuples

Tags: algorithm, haskell, non-deterministic

I'm trying to write a function that will `Nothing` a `Just` `Int` tuple if any two values in the tuple are the same. For a tuple of five values, here's what I've got. Clearly, there's room for improvement:

```
nothingIfMatch :: Maybe (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) -> Maybe (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)
nothingIfMatch Nothing = Nothing
nothingIfMatch (Just (a, b, c, d, e))
    | a == b = Nothing
    | a == c = Nothing
    | a == d = Nothing
    | a == e = Nothing
    | b == c = Nothing
    | b == d = Nothing
    | b == e = Nothing
    | c == d = Nothing
    | c == e = Nothing
    | d == e = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just (a, b, c, d, e)
```

Considering there are "n choose 2" possible intersections for an n-tuple, in this case, there are only 10 options. But imagine this were an 8-tuple, with 28 possibilities, or a 10-tuple, with 45.

There has to be a more idiomatic way to do this, probably relying on non-determinism features.

How should this be done?

Comment: If you need to store an arbitrary number of only one type of data in a structure, you probably want to use some kind of list, instead of a tuple. Consider e.g. `Maybe [Int]` or `Maybe (Vector Int)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can first produce a list of `Int`s and then perform all equality checks:

```
import Data.List(tails)

twoEqual :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
twoEqual xs = any (uncurry elem) [(h, t) | (h:t) <- tails xs]
```

Here we first generate for every element in the list a tuple containing the element and the *rest* of the list. Then we perform `elem` functions: we call `elem` on the item and the rest of the list and in case `any` of these checks holds, then we return `True`, `False` otherwise.

So now we can construct a list from this tuple and then use a guard to perform the checks:

```
nothingIfMatch :: Eq a => Maybe (a, a, a, a, a) -> Maybe (a, a, a, a, a)
nothingIfMatch = (>>= f)
    where f r@(a, b, c, d, e) | twoEqual [a, b, c, d, e] = Nothing
                              | otherwise = Just r
```

We can easily add one extra element to the tuple and add it to the list in the `twoEqual` call. Here we still perform *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. We can do it in *O(n log n)* if we can order the elements first, or we can even do it in *O(n)* in case the elements are *hashable* and no hash collisions occur.

For example:

```
-- O(n log n) if the elements can be ordered

import Data.List(sort, tails)

twoEqual :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
twoEqual xs = or [h1 == h2 | (h1:h2:_) <- tails (sort xs)]
```

Or in case the elements can be hashed:

```
-- O(n) in case the elements are hashable and no hash collisions

import Data.Hashable(Hashable)
import Data.HashSet(fromList, member)

twoEqual :: (Hashable a, Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
twoEqual xs = any (flip member hs) xs
    where hs = fromList xs
```

Comment: For future reader's sake, mind adding some info on how this works?

Comment: In the "no-`Ord`-available" case, one can write `twoEqual xs = xs == Data.List.nub xs`. I like this for its brevity and modularity; especially because once you understand it, you can immediately write down the "`Ord`-available" case in an almost identical matter: `twoEquals xs_ = xs == Data.List.Ordered.nub xs where xs = sort xs_`.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept this answer. Just read it again, and it was a great answer!